# Invoke-WebRequest not working in Azure Automation

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation, powershell-workflow

`Invoke-WebRequest` is not working in Azure.
I have tested the same code in Powershell ISE and it works.

Here is the error:

```
4/8/2015 9:24:14 AM, Error: Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Error : aa00-csmo-t2 - Could not download https://nage1.blob.core.w
indows.net/application/applicationcertificates.7z?sv=2014-02-14&sr=c&sig=ke1lxWQM%3D&se=2016-04-07T06%3A04%3A49Z&sp=r - 
At Install-Certificates:168 char:168
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorCommand
```

Here is the code I was using in Powershell ISE which works:

```
workflow test
{
    $ApplicationCertsBlobUrl = 'https://nage1.blob.core.w
indows.net/application/applicationcertificates.7z?sv=2014-02-14&sr=c&sig=ke1lxWQM%3D&se=2016-04-07T06%3A04%3A49Z&sp=r'

    $applicationCertsZipFileSource = 'C:\Temp\test.7z'

    Invoke-WebRequest $ApplicationCertsBlobUrl -OutFile $applicationCertsZipFileSource
}
```

I have also tried:

```
InlineScript
            {
                $client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
                $client.DownloadFile($using:ApplicationCertsBlobUrl, $using:applicationCertsZipFileSource)
            }
```

However I get this Exception:

```
4/8/2015 9:40:14 AM, Error: Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At Install-Certificates:164 char:164
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to wrap `Invoke-WebRequest` in an `InlineScript`.